# Mi pad 2 установка linux

Tags: android, linux, intel

У меня планшет с предустановленный `windows 10`, на нем есть `bios` и можно загрузиться флешки. Хочу поставить `kali`, но обычная сборка не прошивается, если ставить `nethunter` - тоже ошибка, потому что архитектура процессора не позволяет. Какие есть варианты залить себе рабочий `linux` (deploy и тд пробовал, не работает)

Comment: Модель планшета можно?

Comment: скорее всего на планшете процессор arm, а Вы пытаетесь туда впихнуть x86.

Comment: посмотри http://4pda.ru/forum, раздел форум (находишь свой планшет), а дальше смотреть надо

Answer (score 1):

[*kali nethunter*](https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-nethunter/) — это сборка для процессоров *arm*, а в [*mi pad 2*](http://4pda.ru/2016/03/17/284390/) стоит самый обыкновенный 64-битный *intel*.

[выбирайте любую](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) (без слова *arm* в названии) сборку, хоть 32-битную, хоть 64-битную, и устанавливайте.

в [документации](http://ru.docs.kali.org/installation-ru/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-kali-linux-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) приведена подробная инструкция. с картинками.

---

прежде чем устанавливать, имеет смысл просто опробовать работу live-системы: всё ли оборудование нормально функционирует — видеокарта, wifi, bluetooth, touchscreen и т.д.